# An updated version of drawing text with UIGraphicsImageRender

Tags: swift, uiimage, uigraphicsimagerenderer

Using Swift 5, iOS 14

I put together this code to write text to an image using a UIGraphicsImageRenderer.

It works, but I wondering if I am mixing old with new here. Is there a better way of doing this perhaps, not using NSAttributedStrings which will surely be rendered obsolete in the coming year or two.

```
func returnTile(text: String) -> UIImage {
  let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 64, height: 128))
  return renderer.image { (context) in
    context.cgContext.setStrokeColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
    context.stroke(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height: 128))

    let attributes = [
      NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body),
      NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white
    ]
    text.draw(in: CGRect(x: 32, y: 64, width: 64, height: 128), withAttributes: attributes)
    }
  }
```

Comment: ```let header = text as NSString```  for this ```as NSString``` is not required.

Comment: Thanks Raja, I will update the question

Comment: It's the way I still do it (for what that's worth!) although just`text.draw(in ....)` should be fine